Visual Studio 2022 FileNotFoundException by accessing dll without local copy
I'm using my own DLL in my projects for months without any problems. The DLL is integrated without a local copy, the DLLs are all stored in a directory from where they are integrated. The path is correct and the file definitely exists!
Recently I have had the problem that the compiler reports the following error:
FileNotFoundException: The file or assembly "My.Extensions.IO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" or a dependency on it was not found. The system cannot find the specified file.
The error only occurs when you want to access the DLL. If you don't use the DLL even though it is integrated, it doesn't complain and the project runs without problems.
However, as soon as I want to access a method or property of the DLL, it reports this error.
I have already seen a few solutions to this or similar problems, but none of them helped me.

I have removed the .suo file
I deleted the entire .vs
I removed the reference entry in the .csproj file
I unchecked and rechecked the build checkboxes in the configuration manager for both Debug as and release
I tried out building as release

Nothing helps so far...
If I set the reference to local copy = true, it works, but I don't want to do that because I don't want to ship the DLL every time.
I use Visual Studio 2022 Professional
Does anyone have any ideas on what else I can test besides the things I've already tested?
Thanks

Most likely the version of the dll was wrong.  This often happens when you change the target version of Net.  Removing the reference and then adding the reference usually corrects the version issue.  The adding gets the version of the library dll that is installed on your system.  Net/Core the build machine and deploy machine must have the same version of dlls for code to work.  When you publish with Net the build machine dlls are installed on the publish machine.  In Core the dlls are in the Core library.  The version of Core must be the same on build and deploy.

Thanks @jdweng I didn't wrote that, sorry. The corresponding framework is the same and unchanged. The version of the DLL has not changed either. Everything has really stayed the same and old projects continue to work with this configuration without any problems, only when you create new projects does this error occur. I suspect a bug in the last update of Visual Studio? I currently have 17.10.5 installed

The dll either has to be registered on the machine or has to be in the same folder as the executable.  Check the bin folder of old project and see if dll is in the project folder.  If it is not than the dll was registered.  Where is the dll on old project.  You can open the csproj file in old project with notepad and search for any instructions for the dll.

By using this command line you can add your DLL to GAC if your DLL is strongly named, so that your project can read the DLL from GAC:
gacutil -i [YourDLLPath]


Great! Thank you! That works fine.
